# Бан всех участников с помощью одной команды discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord-api

Нужно чтобы цикл перебирал всех участников на сервере, и с помощью одной команды банил всех разом.

Comment: `msg.members.mentions.first().kick()`, `msg.members.mentions.first().ban()`

Answer (score 1):

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const client = new Discord.Client();
    const prefix = "/"
    const token = "ТВОЙ ТОКЕН"
    
    client.once('ready', () => {
        console.log('Ready!');
    });
    
    client.on('message', message => {
        if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
        if (command === 'banall') {
       message.guild.members.forEach(m => {
    m.ban()
      .catch(console.error);
    });
    
    client.login(token);
```